# Errors logged from a background worker thread via NLog aren't appearing the in the database

Tags: c#, nlog

We are using NLog to log errors and other informational messages to a database. We have recently discovered that NLog messages from background worker threads aren't being logged.

We've got the following defined in our nlog.config file:

```
    <commandText>
      insert into dbo.NLog (
      Application, Logged, Level, Message,
      Username,
      ServerName, Port, Url, Https,
      ServerAddress, RemoteAddress,
      Logger, CallSite, Exception, Duration
      ) values (
      @Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
      @Username,
      @ServerName, @Port, @Url, @Https,
      @ServerAddress, @RemoteAddress,
      @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception, @Duration
      );
    </commandText>

    <parameter name="@application"
               layout="OpSuite.Web"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="50"/>
    <parameter name="@logged"
               layout="${date}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.DateTime"/>
    <parameter name="@level"
               layout="${level}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="50"/>
    <parameter name="@message"
               layout="${message}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="-1"/>
    <parameter name="@username"
               layout="${aspnet-user-identity}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="250"/>
    <parameter name="@serverName"
               layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="-1"/>
    <parameter name="@port"
               layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="-1"/>
    <parameter name="@url"
               layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="-1"/>
    <parameter name="@https"
               layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}"
               />
    <parameter name="@serverAddress"
               layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="100"/>
    <parameter name="@remoteAddress"
               layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="100"/>
    <parameter name="@logger"
               layout="${logger}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="250"/>
    <parameter name="@callSite"
               layout="${callsite}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="-1"/>
    <parameter name="@exception"
               layout="${exception:tostring}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="-1"/>
    <parameter name="@duration"
               layout="${mdc:item=duration}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.Int" />
```

After a bit of trial and error we've tracked the problem down to two of the parameters:

```
    <parameter name="@url"
               layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
               size="-1"/>

    <parameter name="@duration"
               layout="${mdc:item=duration}"
               dbType="SqlDbType.Int" />
```

If we replace both of these definitions with a simple string or integer then the messages get logged.

We are working on the assumption that because the call is from a background worker thread there's no URL and hence no duration defined.

We still need these values populated when called from the main application so how do we setup the configuration to that it works for both cases?

Comment: I'm guessing it is fixed if you use this `<parameter name="@duration" layout="${mdc:item=duration:whenEmpty=0}" dbType="SqlDbType.Int" />`. Notice that `${aspnet}`-LayoutRenderers extracts from the active ASP.NET HttpContext, which is seldom available for background-threads, so it will always return empty-string.

Comment: I guess you can see the actual errors by activating [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting (Make sure never to use `throwExceptions="true"` in production-environment)

Comment: @RolfKristensen I'll give that a go tomorrow. I was trying to find the syntax to test when a parameter was missing but had come up blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `${aspnet}-LayoutRenderers` extracts data from the active ASP.NET HttpContext, which isn't available for background threads, so it will always return an empty string.

Using `:whenEmpty=` will set a value when this isn't available.

The two offending parameters become:

```
<parameter name="@url"
           layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL:whenEmpty=}"
           dbType="SqlDbType.NVarChar" 
           size="-1"/>

<parameter name="@duration"
           layout="${mdc:item=duration:whenEmpty=0}"
           dbType="SqlDbType.Int" />
```

Not putting anything after the `=` in the first case inserts an empty string into the parameter.

Thanks to [Rolf Kristensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193178/rolf-kristensen) for providing the answer in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75524029/errors-logged-from-a-background-worker-thread-via-nlog-arent-appearing-the-in-t?noredirect=1#comment133251756_75524029)

Comment: You only need to use `whenEmpty=` for the `DbType.Int` as the database-server has trouble parsing empty-string-value as valid integer-value. But for `VarChar` then database-server has no issues with empty-string-values (default output when no value).

Comment: @RolfKristensen I found that if I left the `@url` parameter without the `:whenEmpty=` part it still didn't write to the database. It was definitely being executed because I had `:whenEmpty=''` at first and it wrote `''` to the database rather than an empty string.